# Android Studio Gradle Build : Import Eclipse Library Project : Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have a Project in Android Studio and I have added library project in it as per below mentioned link.

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

but I am facing this issue :

***Gradle 'MyApplication2' project refresh failed: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileTree) values: [directory 'libs'] Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)***

Can anyone please help/explain me Gradle build process.

application build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
        compile project(":satellite-menu")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

library build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

application settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':satellite-menu'
project(':satellite-menu').projectDir = new File('libs/satellite-menu')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put your `dependencies` statements in the wrong `dependencies` block in the wrong build file. Dependencies in the `buildscript` block are for telling the build system where to find build system plugins, such as the Android Gradle plugin. For your module dependnecies, put them in the top-level `dependencies` block in the module's build file.

After it's done the top-level build file should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
...
```

and the module's should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(":satellite-menu")
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}

android {
...
```

As for what the meaning is of the actual error message you're getting, it's a little difficult to understand, but essentially the `compile` directive isn't valid in the `dependencies` block under `buildscript` -- the build system doesn't understand it.